# Finding Text and Copying Row to Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

As a novice VBA coder, I have attempted the following in my attached Excel Sheet:

1. Find Text String "CLOCKIFY" or "DROPBOX" in "Expenses-2022" tab/sheet under the "Description" column and
2. Copy the rows that contain either one of those strings
3. Paste each into a row in the "Web-Vendors" tab in the same Excel doc.

I have many more strings to find and add, but I think your help will teach me how to fish and learn how to add the others. The screenshot of my Excel doc is uploaded for clarification (imgur).

Here is my attempt using CLOCKIFY:

```
Sub CopyRowsToWebVendorsTab()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Define source and target worksheets
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2022-Expenses")
    
    ' Check if the target worksheet "CLOCKIFY" exists, create it if not
    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Web-Vendors")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If targetSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        targetSheet.Name = "Web-Vendors"
    End If
    
    ' Find the last row in the source worksheet
    lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in the source sheet
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' Check if the cell in column A of the current row contains "CLOCKIFY"
        If InStr(1, sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, "CLOCKIFY", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            ' Copy the entire row to the target sheet
            sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Clean up
    Set sourceSheet = Nothing
    Set targetSheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image: Image of Excel data]

Comment: Is there some specific issue you're having with your posted code?  If not then what is the question you have about it?

Comment: It looks like the values you want to find are in Col D, but you're searching in Col A?

Comment: Hi Tim, 

Yep, looks like "D" vs "A" could be the problem. I will give that a try. I was getting an error about a local problem but could have done a better job explaining the exact error.

Comment: Is source sheet name "2022-Expenses" (used in code) or "Expenses-2022" (mentioned in post)?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the Stack Overflow rule. Is there a better way to explain the issue? Your comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Use a text table. How to do so is explained in the help that is available when writing or editing your question. Use the `?` icon to show the help menu, and then select `Tables` from the right-end of the menu bar that appears below the icons. For future reference: Images should be used only when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, such as a rendering problem. The only exception to that rule is for a language where code is written using an image editor (there is one such language, but I can't think of its name off-hand).

Answer (score 0):

Here's your original code, commented out, followed by changed code lines:

```
Sub CopyRowsToWebVendorsTab()

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim searchString As Variant
Dim found As Boolean

' Define source and target worksheets
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2022-Expenses")

' Check if the target worksheet "Web-Vendors" exists, create it if not
On Error Resume Next
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Web-Vendors")
On Error GoTo 0
If targetSheet Is Nothing Then
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    targetSheet.Name = "Web-Vendors"
End If

' Find the last row in the source worksheet
lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'' Original code
' ' Loop through each row in the source sheet
' For i = 1 To lastRow
'     ' Check if the cell in column A of the current row contains "CLOCKIFY"
'     If InStr(1, sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, "CLOCKIFY", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
'         ' Copy the entire row to the target sheet
'         sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
'     End If
' Next i

' Define search strings in an array
searchStrings = Array("CLOCKIFY", "DROPBOX")

' Loop through each row in the source sheet
For i = 1 To lastRow
    found = False
    
    ' Loop through each search string
    For Each searchString In searchStrings
        If InStr(1, sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value, searchString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next searchString
    
    ' If a match is found, copy the entire row
    If found Then
        sourceSheet.Rows(i).Copy targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
    End If
Next i

Set sourceSheet = Nothing
Set targetSheet = Nothing

End Sub
```